# geom_smooth only adding lines to my figure legend, not the plot itself

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add regression lines to my graph. `geom_smooth` only adds lines to my figure legend however.

Is the current code I've tried (geom_smooth has the exact same result) along with various attempts at tinkering myself. DGRP.Line & Diet is a factor while Weighted.average is an integer.

```
RENA <- read.csv('RENA.csv')
RENAVG  <-     aggregate(Weighted.average~Diet+DGRP.Line, data = RENA, FUN = sum) 

ggplot(RENAVG, aes(x=DGRP.Line, y=Weighted.average, colour=Diet))+
    geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method='lm')
```

I'm not sure if the failure to properly regress is a consequence of DGRP.Line being a factor or not. But I'd expect geom_smooth to just form regression lines from my .csv file anyway (RENAVG)

On another attempt using the main RENA.CSV I get this error

> "`mapping` must be created by `aes()`"

but I'm not sure if that's relevant to the RENAVG I made on R.

My graph is included below. As you can see the figure legend is lined, but no regression lines are on the actual data set.

[image: Graph]

Edit: 
I tried converting my original ggplot (excluding smooth) to its own 'RENAVGPLOT'. Then added smooth in as RENAVGPLOT _ Geom_Smooth, resulting in: Error: Don't know how to add RENAVGPLOT to a plot

```
dput(RENAVG)
structure(list(Diet = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", 
"Rena"), class = "factor"), DGRP.Line = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("105a", "105b", 
"348", "354", "362a", "362b", "391a", "391b", "392", "397", "405", 
"486a", "486b", "712", "721", "737", "757a", "757b", "853", "879"
), class = "factor"), Weighted.average = c(3.618181818, 7.516666667, 
7.5, 10.464285714, 5.830882353, 7.0625, 6.411392405, 7.413953488, 
6.079053054, 7.0375, 6.373640273, 10.406521739, 6.948020792, 
9.851458886, 9.176727909, 10.164712153, 6.23826291, 11.023310023, 
7.908730159, 9.537815126, 5.314323607, 6.655822854, 5.669226044, 
7.818181818, 4.761481935, 9.468873129, 6.577764637, 12.170588235, 
5.742087177, 10.529411765, 8.891608391, 2, 11.036572623, 3, 9.739878543, 
9.782051282, 7.741384687, 8.739583333)), row.names = c(NA, -38L
), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Example of what I'd like

```
mtcars
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, colour=cyl)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()
```

Comment: We have no access to your data. Please provide a sample with `dput`. Use `dput(head(df,n))`. When adding details, click **edit not write a comment below your post.**

Comment: Thanks, I'll ensure to do that in future

Comment: Is there any reason to use `aggregate`? I would think setting `colour` does what `aggregate` should do, no? See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html).

Comment: Your _DGRP Line_ field looks to be a categorical field. If that is in fact the case, this would explain why ggplot can't "connect" your lines requested by `geom_smooth`

Comment: Aggregate was used as I had both male/female samples and wanted to tally them as a total rather than separate on this graph in particular.

Comment: Could you use a built in data set to show what kind of graph you need. **Please also add data as requested already.**

Comment: Sorry, added it in

Comment: I get the feeling I may have been attempting this with the wrong graph, it seemed strange to use a regression curve for this data set. But still I appreciate the help and the categorical data is something I'll keep in note in future! One day I'll know how to use R properly...

Comment: I think this question should be asked on Cross Validated. Using `as.numeric` for `DRP.LINE` will yield the desired result but whether that is statistically correct is another issue. The problem therefore seems to be more about the correct smoothing to apply rather than the code itself.

Comment: Thanks, I separated each DGRP.Line and made a regression curve for their individual count and Day to see when their count (aka hatching) stops. A little unrelated but I think this is the graph I actually should've been looking at in the first place.